# Maven downloads wrong transitive dependency

Tags: java, xml, maven

***PROBLEM:***

Maven downloads wrong non-classifier transitive dependency.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This produces following result in dependencies:

[image]

It is obviously wrong, because non-classifier javafx-base is empty and creates mess.

***WORKAROUND:***

It seems to be fixed when I excluse transitive dependency and manually declare javafx-base as dependency, like that:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the result, I get this:

[image]

***QUESTION:***

Is there any solution to my problem that doesn't utilize some bad practice workaround?

***ADDITIONAL SOURCE:***

[openjfx maven repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/)

Comment: Maven does nothing wrong, javafx-base is a compile dependency of javafx-graphics so it'll become a dependency. What do you mean by "and creates mess." ? That sounds like a personal opinion, not a problem.

Comment: @Gimby By "creates mess" I mean, for example, non-classifier library pops up in module-info as javafx-baseEmpty, so it's error-prone (as correct module is javafx-base)

Comment: The full pom file would be very helpful and also error/log output...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you have to explicitly mess around with the classifiers yourself? This is normally not needed at all. Just follow the examples given in the official documentation.

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: That's because my application is multi-platform, that means I build separate versions for Windows, Linux and Mac. All of the different versions should use platform-related version of libraries (e.g. javafx for linux, mac, etc.)

Comment: You should build each version on a machine running the respective OS. Cross-platform building is not really supported especially if you want to create a proper installer bundle.